# Can I do multiple error handling with single line code on .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently working on a project using `PHP`. I need to know whether I can do multiple error handling with just a line of code. Multiple error means `404 or 403 or 400 or any https-status-error`.In general to do this sort of error handling we should write;

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
```

But I want to minimize the code and redirect all https-status-error code to a single page.Instead of writing the code below is there any short alternative;

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php
```